# How to write a validation rule for white-listed input (such as "t" || "f")?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an issue where when I add a rule for a jQuery validation I get the default error message:

> Please enter the same value again.

No matter what I input the error message still holds.

This is my rule: Is it correct?

```
$( "#answer" ).rules( "add", {
  maxlength: 1,
  equalTo: ("t" || "f" || "T" || "F"),
  messages: {
    required: "Required input - answer T or f",
    maxlength: jQuery.format("Please, T or f")
  }
});
```

Comment: `"t" || "f" || "T" || "F"` evaluates to `"t"` (it is equivalent of saying: `equalTo: "t"`); thus the posted code is not correct.

Comment: @user2864740 how can I evaluate it to either?

Comment: It *cannot* be done using that syntax (or any expression which is entirely immediately evaluated). I suspect there is a way to use a *function* to validate input, but I quickly gave up trying to understand the validation documentation.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?  Post enough code to reproduce the issue including the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
equalTo: ("t" || "f" || "T" || "F"),
```

That is not how you use the `equalTo` rule.

See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/

> "Description: Requires the element to be the **same as another one**"

In other words, the `equalTo` method is only used for comparing two fields to each other, and the parameter can only be a selector that targets the other field.

If you're trying to match characters, then you'll need to write a regular expression (regex) and use the `pattern` method included in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js).

Alternative to regex, you could write a custom rule using [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  Maybe something like...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("torf", function(value, element) {
    return (value == "T"  || value == "F");
}, "Enter T or f");
```

applied like...

```
$( "#answer" ).rules( "add", {
    torf: true,
    ....
```